# What is the maximum length of a Dailymotion video title?

Tags: dailymotion-api

What characters can I use in a Dailymotion video title (UTF-8) ? Are there any forbidden chars ("<>") ? And what is the maximum length of a video title ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of a video needs to have a length between 1 and 255 characters and accepts any UTF-8 charater.
You can find  all the list of our guidelines here: [API guidelines](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/partners#guidelines)